# VS2015 vector iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++

I have a little problem, I have to build a 2D game based on SDL.

I just keep getting this errror when I try to delete 2 objects that are colliding in "Scene".

```
std::vector<WaspObject*>::iterator itw;
std::vector<ProjectileObject*>::iterator itp;

for (itp = _projectiles.begin(); itp != _projectiles.end();)
{
    for (itw = _wasps.begin(); itw != _wasps.end();)
    {
        if ((*itw)->Get_PositionY() + 37 >= (*itp)->Get_PositionY() + 0 && (*itp)->Get_PositionX()+0 >= (*itw)->Get_PositionX()+0 && (*itp)->Get_PositionX()+0 <= (*itw)->Get_PositionX()+49)
        {
            itw = _wasps.erase(itw);
            itp = _projectiles.erase(itp);
        }
        else
        {
            itw++;
            itp++;
        }
    }
}
```

_wasps and _projectiles are std vectors in this scene.

Can someone help me find the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get any hits and increment `itp` in the inner loop, it might well run past `_projectiles.end()`.

For example if there are more wasps than projectiles. Or if you are on the last projectile, where you will reach `_projectiles.end()` after a single `itp++`.

So you might want to test *both* end conditions at each turn of the inner loop.